# Fetching last 100 row from mysql not working | JSON fromat

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to fetch the last 100 row but only one row is being displayed as a result

here is my php code:

```
<?php

require_once("variables.php");
$db = new ezSQL_mysql($GLOBALS['database_username'],$GLOBALS['database_password'],$GLOBALS['database_database'],$GLOBALS['database_server']);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo "{\"office\":\"0\",\"dept\":{\"desk\":[";
$symbols = addslashes($_GET['symbols']);

$symbolsArr = explode(",", $symbols);
foreach($symbolsArr as $s) {

    $last = $db->get_row("select * from data where name='$s' order by id desc limit 0,100");

    $jsonArray = array('name' => $s, 
                        'phone' => $last->phone, 
                        'active' => $last->active);


    echo json_encode($jsonArray);}
    echo "]}}";

?>
```

**UPDATE**> based on recommendations below I have changed get_row to get_results but the code broken now and it's not displaying any error.

Comment: For testing measures, I would include more 'echo' statements in your 'foreach' loop.

Comment: 1. addslashes is *not* sufficient to escape SQL parameters and avoid SQL injection. Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or the respective method of your DB class. 2. You could also `json_encode` the `"{\"office\"…` stuff; no need to write literal JSON yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation on the database class you are using (ezSQL):

```
----------------------------------------------------
Example 2
----------------------------------------------------

// Get one row from the database..
$user = $db->get_row("SELECT name,email FROM users WHERE id = 2");

echo $user->name;
echo $user->email;
```

You are issuing a statement that is specifically to fetch one single row.

What you want to use is `get_results()` method instead of `get_row()` method.

I re-read your question and see that you were doing limit 0,100 which returns 100 rows starting with 0 (first). i thought you were trying to cycle those rows but I can see you are actually trying to only get the last row... my bad, derp.. well here - you are reversed somewhat in your query - should be 100,1 as you want the 100th row and only 1 row.

```
$last = $db->get_row("select * from data where name='{$s}' order by id desc limit 100,1");

    $jsonArray = array('name' => $s, 
                        'phone' => $last->phone, 
                        'active' => $last->active);
```

Comment: Oh sorry I am very php beginner and didn't notice this mistake. I have tried this on the same but didn't fetch any data and no error appeared:
$last = $db->get_results("select * from data where name='$s' order by id desc limit 0,100");

Comment: before you run the statement, do echo "select * from data where name='$s' order by id desc limit 0,100"; and then run that query on the sql server to verify it returns results please.

Comment: Sorry maybe I am missing something I couldn't understand your advice. I think I have to do more research into ezSQL.

Comment: I generally try not to link 3rd party sites but this link explains more about usage cases for this library: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/790-PHP-Makes-using-mySQL-ridiculously-easy-great-docs-.html

Comment: Could you please advise on how the code should be after replacing get_row with get_results?

Comment: edited, i misread your question and only looked at the query first. this should work :p

Comment: Thank you again. but I think first you were right. I have to use get_results because I need to fetch all last 100 rows not only one row. But that didn't work and broke my code with no error :(

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to get last 100 rows use following statement:

```
$last = $db->get_results("select * from data where name='$s' order by id desc limit 100");
```

instead of

```
$last = $db->get_row("select * from data where name='$s' order by id desc limit 0,100");
```

[ezSql get_results](http://www.fiazhusyn.com/2014/11/22/function-reference-get_results-ezsql/) is the method which you need to use for retrieving multiple results from database.